# How can I connect input form in HTML to Database Table via ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection

I have a button in my HTML code in an ASP project. The method `Button1_Click()` in aspx.cs where I actually define my connection and insert values to a table.

This is a snippet from aspx where I call `Button1_Click()`:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="button"
           onclick="checking(); Button1_Click();"
           value="Check aviability"
           id="buttoncheck">
</form>
```

When I type something in my form on the website, and then click the button, no data gets inserted to my SQL Server table.

Code for `Button1_Click()`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        string SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO[dbo].[User_search] (
            [Name],[Surname],[In_date],[Out_date]," +
            "[People_num],[In_business],[Email],[Phone_number])" +
            "Values(@Name, @Surname, @In_date, @Out_date, @People_num," +
            "@In_business, @Email, @Phone_number)";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLInsert, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The values aren't added to DB table. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no way for us to know unless you show us *"where I actually define my connection and insert values to a table."*

Comment: @wazz already edited

Comment: You have to set the actual values of the parameters (`@Name`, etc.). [Here's an example](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access) with MS Access, but it's similar with other DBs. Search here or online for 'parameter queries'.

Comment: @wazz I've been searching for a while but didn`t find how to fix that :(

Comment: first of all the `Button1_Click` is not called, second you do not define the sql parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In ASP.NET WebForm Project, `Button_Click()` is a code-behind function, so in your HTML code (.aspx), the button should be declared in this form:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

2. In your code-behind class (xxxx.aspx.cs), `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` method will be triggered when the Button1 is clicked. And your function is to execute an insert SQL, but it misses some parameters.... I have no idea what the datatype is, so I assume the parameters are string:

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO[dbo].[User_search] (
            [Name],[Surname],[In_date],[Out_date]," +
            "[People_num],[In_business],[Email],[Phone_number])" +
            "Values(@Name, @Surname, @In_date, @Out_date, @People_num," +
            "@In_business, @Email, @Phone_number)";
            
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLInsert, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = "test1";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Surname"].Value = "test2";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@In_date", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@In_date"].Value = "test3";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Out_date", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Out_date"].Value = "test4";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@People_num", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@People_num"].Value = "test5";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@In_business", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@In_business"].Value = "test6";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = "test7";
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone_number", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Phone_number"].Value = "test8";

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I see that button is actually working, because after pressing it the input dissapears. But still nothing changes in my db table. I think the problem now is in my connection string, because I`m using windows authentication and maybe I didn't write it in appropriate way. Every website says different way, but nothing works for me.

Comment: @Solomia00 Maybe you can try to add a connection string with UserId/Password version. And check if there is any exception in the catch block.